# WAMP error en acceso por puerto 8080

Tags: wamp, puertos

tengo corriendo sobre un pc con windows 10 un WAMP 3.2.3 con Apache 2.4.46. Tengo un proyecto funcional configurado con wordpress en la carpeta C:/wamp64/www/miproyecto y tengo creado un virtual server del mismo (miproyecto.local:8080). Apache escucha en el puerto 8080 (por motivos que no vienen al caso). Por otro lado tengo realizado un forward hacia el puerto 8080 en el router, configurada una ddns para acceder a mi ip pública con un dominio (miproyecto.ddns.net) y realizadas excepciones en el firewall.

Puedo acceder a la pagina principal de wamp desde el pc servidor de la siguiente manera:
http://localhost:8080

Puedo acceder sin problemas desde la LAN con un ordenador externo hasta la pagina principal de wamp de la siguiente manera:
http://ipservidor:8080

Puedo acceder sin problemas hasta la pagina principal de wamp desde internet de la siguiente manera:
http://middns.ddns.net (se redirecciona automático a http://middns.ddns.net:8080)

Puedo acceder sin problemas a mi proyecto wordpress desde el pc servidor de las siguientes maneras:
localhost:8080/miproyecto
miproyecto.local:8080

Obtengo un error intentando entrar a mi proyecto de las siguientes maneras:
Accediendo desde cualquier ordenador de la LAN hasta mi proyecto
http://ipservidor:8080/miproyecto
http://ipservidor:8080/miproyecto.local:8080
Accediendo desde internet hasta mi proyecto:
http://miproyecto.ddns.net/miproyecto
http://miproyecto.ddns.net/miproyecto.local:8080

En concreto el error que devuelve el servidor en todos los casos es:
Forbidden, you don't have premission to acces this resource.
Apache/2.4.46(Win64) PHP/7.3.21 Server at miproyecto.ddns.net Port 80

(aqui me pierdo, no se porqué intenta localizar mi proyecto por el puerto 80 antes he podido acceder al mismo por el 8080 y el httpd-vhosts.conf el servidor virtual está en el 8080).

Siempre obtengo el mismo error, excepto en el caso:http://miproyecto.ddns.net/miproyecto que directamente no responde (timed out)

Los logs para el acceso a internet me indican los siguiente:
[core:error] [pid 10556:tid 1148] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client x.x.x.x:54699] AH00127: Cannot map GET /miproyecto.local:8080 HTTP/1.1 to file

Lo curioso es que si configuro todo para que Apache trabaje en el puerto 80 desaparecen todos estos problemas, pero necesito trabajar en otro puerto.

Googleando he visto que es posible que windows tenga problemas con el carácter ":" pero tampoco he encontrado una posible solución (imagino que algún archivo de configuracion puede tener alguna expresión regular manipulable para solucionarlo) si es que ese es el problema. En fin, parece algo tonto, pero no doy con la clave. Cualquier aclaración, guía u orientación de la comunidad será muy agradecida.

Comment: Revisa tu archivo `httpd.conf` y dinos qué hay en él al lado de `Listen`. Me parece que desde wamp puedes también cambiar el puerto por defecto, desde `Tools` o algo así

Comment: Hay algo mal en la configuración del WAMP o del DDNS; está poniendo el puerto al final de la URL.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Wamp si escucha, recibe peticiones por el puerto 8080, lo configuré así, el propio wamp tiene una herramienta para verificarlo, de hecho puedo acceder por ese puerto a la página principal de wamp. Por otro lado Httpd.conf indica: Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080. El puerto al final de la url es el modo de acceder a un virtualhost cuando el puerto no es el 80, el propio wamp así lo indica al crear un virtualhost con esas condiciones. Probablemente el : de ese puerto genere el problema pero no sé donde corregirlo, es posible que solo suceda en windows.

Comment: ¿En `Tools` puedes ver una sección llamada `Port used by Apache` o parecido? ¿Qué ves en esa sección?

Comment: Si, ya he hecho un test en tool y si apache escucha perfectamente en 8080. De hecho puedo acceder a la configuración de wamp desde fuera poniendo en la URL 8080 como he dicho antes. El problema es de permisos para acceder al proyecto desde fuera del servidor, esto es porque puede faltar alguna autorización o porque al procesar el carácter : en el final de la URL Windows no lo reconoce. Sinceramente no lo sé, pero es lo que he visto como posible. Me llama la atención que a nadie más le haya pasado, no creo ser el único que intenta acceder desde fuera con un 8080 a un proyecto en wamp windows